OpenIdConnect error "Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid" when upgrading to .NET 8.0.x
This is not a question, I just would like to share the solution to resolve this issue to save time for anyone that met the same problem with me when upgrading the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect to version 8.0.6.
I am using an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API (Cookie, OIDC, JWT).
Here's the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 

Authentication configuration:
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = " {clientId}";
    options.ClientSecret = "{clientSecret}";
    options.Authority = "{authority}";

    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("role");
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
});

The reason of this is that we're missing the package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect since it's required for new version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, but I don't know why it's not a dependency while we installing the package.

If you want to share you could firstly add an answer and put a solution inside it and mark it to help other folks who faced the same error

So the solution is simple, just install Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect corresponding to the version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect that you installed and the issue is solved without adding any new line of code.

Thank you very much.  Also, I wish there was more explanation.

worked for me, thanks!

Ugg.. thanks for taking the time to add this, I was starting to go a little crazy

Jess, it appears to be a straight up bug.  If you add Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect and specifically add version 7.1.2, you'll still get the bad behavior.  It's called out in the dependency section of Nuget Package Manager.  And it says >=7.1.2.  But that's a lie.  Install >=8.whatever.
